# Clearing Cooking in Express

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I am setting a cookie like below in a post function.

```
 res.cookie('sessionID', req.sessionID, { path: '/' });
```

It sets it fine...but I cannot seem to delete it.  I am deleting it in a put function, because I want to update some data and then clear the cookie.

```
app.put('/data/completed/:info', jsonParser, function(req, res){
    if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400)
  res.clearCookie('sessionID', { path: '/' });
  console.log(req.cookies.sessionID);
});
```

Obviously I am doing something wrong I just can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue wasn't with the clearing of the cookie it was with me not ending the response process.  As clarified on the Express documentation.

> res.end([data] [, encoding])
>
> Ends the response process. This method actually comes from Node core,
>   specifically the response.end() method of http.ServerResponse.
>
> Use to quickly end the response without any data. If you need to
>   respond with data, instead use methods such as res.send() and
>   res.json().

So when I put the res.end() function in the code, everything works as expected and the cookie clears.

```
app.put('/reset/:completed',function(req,res){

  res.clearCookie('sessionID', { path: '/' });

  res.end();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are clearing cookie of response. But checking for request. Try to check console.log(re**s**.cookies.sessionID);

Comment: It didn't work. When I check res.cookies.sessionID it says it is undefined.  Plus it didn't clear the cookie I can still see it.

Comment: It must work. This particular code should work. Try read more here. http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie and here http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.clearCookie